# Как лучше разобрать словарь в шаблоне Django?

Tags: python, django

Нужно в шаблоне разобрать словарь вот такого вида.

```
dict = {'value': 200, 'n': 300}
```

Проблема в том, что ключ `n` не меняется, а ключ `value` может быть любым, потому что словарь создается в процессе итерации объекта, в котором много таких словарей.

Каждый раз я могу обратиться к значению n очень просто:

```
{{dict.n}}
```

Но как обратиться к значению `value`? Пока я не придумал ничего лучше кастомного тега:

```
@register.filter
def by_index(dictionary, position):
    return list(dictionary.values())[int(position)]
```

Ну и соответственно обращаюсь к значению в шаблоне вот так:

```
{{dict|by_index:0}}
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что это плохой вариант.
Нет ли способа получше?

Comment: `dictionary.values()` в общем случае сортируется случайным образом, так что этот вариант не плохой, а просто нерабочий

Comment: Но то ли я не понял задачи, то ли ничто не должно мешать сделать `return dictionary[position]` и `{{dict|by_index:"value"}}`

Comment: Выглядит как проблема плохо выбранного формата данных. Или даже плохо выбранная структура данных. В словаре всегда два элемента?

Comment: Да, в словаре 2 элемента. Этот словарь получается из вот такой выборки в контроллере: 'primer': all_products.values('primer').annotate(n=models.Count("pk")). Возвращается список словарей вот такого вида. Я записываю в переменную несколько таких выборок, для того, чтобы в шаблоне можно было по ним итерироваться и написать шаблон одним циклом, т.к. для каждой выборки в шаблоне все одинаково.

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров тогда зачем вам словарь? Почему бы не преобразовать вывод ORM в список двухэлементных списков или кортежей?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я сейчас так попробовал сделать. Все работает и все просто, но смущает один момент. Раньше выполнение вьюхи замнимало 0.002 с, а теперь 0.2 с. Замедление в 100 раз. Делаю вот что, сначала как в предыдущем комментарии записываю кверисет в переменную primer. А потом распаковываю его вот так  [[elem['primer'], elem['n']] for elem in primer],

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev странно, что это так долго. Всего таких словарей во вьюхе 7, в каждом где-то по 20-30 значений. А сами выборки происходят из pg, из таблицы, в которой 60 000 значений и все выбирается очень быстро. Как-то обидно выходит)

Comment: Возможно это связано с тем, что `QuerySet` _ленив_ и раньше его _вычисление_ происходило где-то в другом месте.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, возможно, но в любом случае это значит, что к предыдущему времени прибавилось еще 0,2 с на очень простую операцию :(

Comment: Если моё предположение верно, то стоит попробовать воспользоваться union'ом для объединения семи запросов в один и генераторным выражением вместо спискового включения, для сохранения _ленивости_.